# Count number of rows until given value in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli

I've searched for quite a while for an answer to this with no luck.  Sorry if this is answered somewhere I couldn't find.

I basically have a queue in a MySQL table and I need to tell people what number they are in the queue using PHP.

Right now, I've got this, but all it does is count the number of rows in the table:

```
$rowquery = "SELECT * FROM restaurant_guests ORDER BY ID UNTIL";
if ($stmt = $mysqli2->prepare($rowquery)) {

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* store result */
$stmt->store_result();

printf("%d", $stmt->num_rows - 1);

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}
```

Can someone please help point me in the right direction?  Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM restaurant_guests WHERE ID < 100;` ?

Comment: If you know the ID, just count the number of results meeting criteria (eg. having `ID` lower than specific user's, and not executed yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a minute. Are the ID auto-incremented?
If only the guests with lower ID goes out of the queue first, then
wouldn't it be better to just give:

```
answer = (the ID of user in question) - (lowest ID of the user in the queue) + 1
```

where the lowest ID of the user in the queue can be queried by:

```
SELECT ID from restaurant_guests ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1
```

At least, this approach will transfer a constant number of data from the DBMS in contrast with other approaches.

Comment: Can you help point me in the right direction for finding the lowest ID of the user in the queue?  Thank you!

Comment: As requested. But I'm not sure if MySQL use the the keyword `LIMIT` or `TOP`.

Comment: I don't see how this is a correct solution.  It doesn't account for the fact that there might be gaps in the auto-increment sequence.  If there are missing records (that have been deleted for one reason or another), this solution would over-estimate the desired number.  The only way to definitively get this answer is to count the number of values with a queue sequence number (the `id` field in this case I believe) less than or equal to the queue number of the user you are interested in.

Comment: @MikeBrant As in the first line of answer: "If only the guests with lower ID goes out of the queue first". I have stated the assumption.

Comment: @Billiska That still could lead to overcounting unless you are guaranteed that every row in the table is sequentially numbered and there are no gaps present in the numbering.  Take a case where you have 100 records with IDs 1-100.  In this case your calculation would return a value of 100 which is correct.  Now, what happens if rows 7, 25, 42, 68, and 81 have been removed?  Your calculation would still return 100, which is incorrect, as the number of items in the table with id <= 100 is 95.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, yes, you should see that I do understand you counter example. However, when I say only "lower ID goes out first", I mean that 7 never gets removed before 1 and such. So the assumption covers it. If you think the assumption is not clearly worded, you're welcomed to edit it. Your answer is correct without further assumption and I like it. I put my answer here as a complement to yours since I think OP might find the assumption applicable.

Answer (score 2):

If the ID field is the basis for your queue (i.e. higher the id higher the order in queue), then the query is as simple as counting the number of rows with id values <= to the user's id

```
SELECT count(id) FROM restaurant_guests WHERE id <= ?
```

Here `?` represents the id value you are searching for.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I understand what the query should be and why, but I'm new at PHP and unsure how to go about executing it.  Would you mind explaining how to execute this query?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2395369 There are plenty of resources available to help you with learning how to connect to and interact with MySQL. This is not really something that should be covered within the context of this question.  My main suggestion though would be to look at using mysqli or PDO for your database connection needs.  There is plenty of documentation on how to use these in PHP.net docs as well as sites like StackOverflow.